# Encoding URL parameters in thank you page and decode them with Gravity forms fields

Tags: wordpress, string, woocommerce

I use a WordPress plugin which redirects customers to a personalized thank you page (redirect customers to a new website with a different domain name) by retrieving customer data: order id, billing email, order_total ..etc

Example: https://example1.com/?order_id=139047&order_total=300.00&mail=billing-email@gmail.com&prenom=Joe&nom=Doe&address=123%20Quartier

```
// Return thankyou redirect
                return array(
                    'result'   => 'success',
                    'redirect' => ( '' == $this->custom_return_url ) ?
                        $this->get_return_url( $order ) :
                        apply_filters( 'alg_wc_custom_payment_gateway_custom_return_url',
                            str_replace(
                                array( '%order_id%', '%order_key%', '%order_total%', '%billing_email%', '%billing_last_name%', '%billing_first_name%', '%billing_city%', '%billing_address_1%'  ),
                                array( $order->get_id(), $order->get_order_key(), $order->get_total(), $order->get_billing_email(), $order->get_billing_last_name(), $order->get_billing_first_name(), $order->get_billing_city(), $order->get_billing_address_1() ),
                                htmlspecialchars_decode( $this->custom_return_url )
                            ),
                            $order )
                );
            }
```

Then I recover these data via a Gravity form to dynamically fill in the fields: Email, Name, Address, Amount ...etc

I want to encode the parameters in the URL so as not to expose my customer's data.

Do you have a solution for me please?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just pass the order_id? Then, with that info, you can retrieve your customer info and use it later.

Comment: in my case, I need the Email address to go through URL from website A to website B (I am using thank you page as the checkout page)